# The Breezejs ZUMO example returns the inlineCount as undefined

Tags: breeze, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to get the inlinecount from a breeze query. The results will come back, but the inlineCount property will be undefined. I captured the breeze query and results in Fiddler and they seem to be correct. The server returns the values in Fiddler with a count property added the the json results. I am getting the same results with my own app.

```
   // Get all TodoItems from the server and cache combined
    function getAllTodoItems() {

        // Create the query
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('TodoItem')
       .inlineCount();


        // Execute the query
        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(success).catch(queryFailed);

        function success(data){
            // Interested in what server has then we are done.
            var fetched = data.results;
            $log.log('breeze query succeeded. fetched: '+ fetched.length);

            // Blended results.
            // This gets me all local changes and what the server game me.
            return manager.getEntities(todoItemType);

            // Normally would re-query the cache to combine cached and fetched
            // but need the deleted entities too for this UI.
            // For demo, we returned every cached Todo
            // Warning: the cache will accumulate entities that
            // have been deleted by other users until it is entirely rebuilt via 'refresh'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inlineCount` property will be added by Breeze if you decorate your WebApi Get method with the `BreezeQueryableAttribute` or if you decorate the WebApi controller with the `BreezeControllerAttribute`. Otherwise, you can get the count by calling `data.httpResponse.data.count`.

You can prove this in the todo sample by launching the WebApi server and setting the `uzeZumo` variable to false in the config.js file. This will fetch the records from the WebApi. By default it'll fetch the data from Zumo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Denis, I am developing a mobile app so I will not have a  ASP.NET Web API back-end. I think the data.results.length will give me a count of items returned by the query and not all of the items in the remote store. The query generated by breeze is correct when I add the .inlineCount() to the query. When I inspect it in Fiddler it returns the queried items and a count of the total items. Any ideas?

Comment: You're correct. Sorry for the misinformation. I have edited my response.